# Implementing Typescript interfaces in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses, python-class

I'm looking for some advice on what's the best way of implementing a set of data value only 'interfaces' in Python that are equivalent to their typescript counterpart (we've got a project where we use both, and want to enforce a consistent interface for their communication, which would be via serialising the python into json to pull into the TS component)

The interfaces will be compositions to keep things modular and simple.

Given a set of TS interfaces defined as:

```
interface TestOutput {
  phantom: string
  testDateTime: datetime
  author: string
  result: boolean
  report_summaryFile?: string // the '?' means this field is optional
  // ... more values
  series: Array<Series>
  soloImages: Array<Images>
}

interface Series {
  number: number
  filter: string
  kernel: string
  // ... more values
  images: Array<TestImage>
}
```

I was thinking of using **dataclasses** and doing the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List
import datetime

@dataclass
class TestSeries:
    seriesNum: int 
    modality: str 
    description: str = ''

@dataclass
class TestOutput:
    phantom: str 
    testDateTime: datetime.datetime
    author: str 
    result: bool
    series: List[TestSeries]
    soloImages: List[Images]
    report_summaryFile: str = ''
```

Is dataclasses the best approach for this?

Comment: sounds reasonable. you can plug any dataclass instance into `json.dumps(dataclass.as_dict(my_instance))` to get a valid json string from it, and if you need actual type assertions during runtime rather than type annotations, you can transition to use [`pydantic`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) instead.

Comment: @Arne - great - thanks for your thought.  I'll check pydantic out

Comment: Sure but note, `dataclasses.dataclass` is just a way to create a regular class with less boilerplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pydantic is a good library.
I did something similar, but only for dataclasses - ValidatedDC:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC
import json


@dataclass
class Series(ValidatedDC):
    series_num: int
    modality: str
    description: str = ''


@dataclass
class Output(ValidatedDC):
    phantom: str
    date_time: str
    author: str
    result: bool
    series: List[Series]
    report_summary_file: str = ''


# For example, by API we got a JSON string:
input_json_string = '''
    {
        "phantom": "test_phantom",
        "date_time": "2020.01.01",
        "author": "Peter",
        "result": true,
        "series": [{
            "series_num": 1,
            "modality": "test_modality"
        }]
    }
'''

# Load the string into the dictionary:
input_data = json.loads(input_json_string)

# Then create a dataclass to check the types of values and for the
# convenience of further work with data:
output = Output(**input_data)

# Since valid data were obtained, there are no errors
assert output.get_errors() is None

# Let's say we got data with an error:
input_data['series'][0]['series_num'] = '1'  # The string is not an integer!

output = Output(**input_data)
assert output.get_errors()
print(output.get_errors())
# {
#    'series': [
#        InstanceValidationError(
#            value_repr="{'series_num': '1', 'modal...}",
#            value_type=<class 'dict'>,
#            annotation=<class '__main__.Series'>, exception=None,
#            errors={
#                'series_num': [
#                    BasicValidationError(
#                        value_repr='1', value_type=<class 'str'>,
#                        annotation=<class 'int'>, exception=None
#                    )
#                ]
#            }
#        ),
#        ListValidationError(
#            item_index=0, item_repr="{'series_num': '1', 'modal...}",
#            item_type=<class 'dict'>, annotation=<class '__main__.Series'>
#        )
#    ]
# }
```

See here for more details:
https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc